# Arrays.asList not flattening in Java, what should I use instead?

Tags: java, arrays, integer, sortedset

Hi I need to convert a SortedSet> to an array of integers but not sure how to do it.

This is the SortedSet I want to convert:

```
private SortedSet<List<Integer>> coords;
```

and this is the get method I am using which shows as an error:

```
public List<Integer> getCoords() {
    return Arrays.asList(coords);
}
```

If I want to do something like this, would I have to go through the entire SortedList and make a new int[] array and just put all the values inside it? Or is there a much nicer way? I thought Arrays.asList could do this but now I am confused!

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Your question doest not have enough context. You have a Set of Lists of Integers. Do you want all of the Integers in an array, or do you want to put the Lists inside of the Array?

Comment: The elements of your `Set` are themselves `Collections`; so, what you want is basically to flatten your ints, right?

Comment: Well, a `Set` is not an array. Anyway, you have a set of lists of integers, so what would be the wanted way to turn it to one list? Concatenating the lists?

Comment: You should read the JavaDoc of [`Arrays.asList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29).

Comment: You have a collection of collections and want to convert it to a collection? That's called "flattening". Where does `Arrays.asList` come into it? You don't have an array...

Comment: Your `coords` is a set of lists of integers... What exactly is a "coord"? Are you representing each coord as a list with two elements perhaps?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. A coord is an abbreviation for a pair of x and y coordinates and yes I want to flatten them into a single list and get them out of the SortedSet. I now understand why I cannot use Arrays.asList and will have to iterate through it, it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Arrays.asList()` will not flatten anything!

What you want is this:

```
public List<Integer> getCoords()
{
    final List<Integer> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final List<Integer> l: coords)
        ret.addAll(l);
    return ret;
}
```

With Java 8, **one example** would be:

```
public List<Integer> getCoords()
{
    final List<Integer> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    coords.stream().forEach(ret::addAll);
    return ret;
}
```

There are other, shorter examples (see other answers or comments to this answer) as well.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I just edited the post for that; maybe there is a shorter way, but I don't master all of `.flat*()` yet

Comment: `coords.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new))` is a nice one liner.

Comment: That is true; however I prefer code on more lines but more easily understood by the reader ;)

Comment: Meh, who ever reads code after it's written? (I totally agree, readability over coolness)

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense and prefer this approach. I will stick to the basic forEach loop rather than messing with Java 8 but thanks for showing both.

Comment: Well, if you are using Java 8 you should go at least the `.forEach()` way... Granted, it is not obvious at first what a method reference is, but when you get the hang of some of it, the rest comes naturally ;)

Comment: @Mayron if you are using Java 8 then use it. What you have said is somewhat like sticking with "basic arrays" rather than "messing with Collections".

Answer (score 4):

@fge gives you the solution. However if you are using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) you could use the brand new stream API and call `flatMap` (which is the operation you are looking for).

```
public List<Integer> getCoords() {
        return coords.stream()
                     .flatMap(list -> list.stream()) //or .flatMap(List::stream)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Even `flatMap(Collection::stream)` would work, I believe

Comment: @fge Yes it would. They generate the same bytecode though.

Answer (score 1):

You want to make an array of all the integers inside all the lists in your sorted set?

You'll have to iterate through the set, and concatenate the results of each `list.toArray();`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray(T[])